# Problems with load url in android

Tags: android, webview

i use `Webview` component for load `url` in my app. but this component is very slow in load `url`

how to slove this problem?

thank you and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: If the internet connection is slow, then definitely slow loading.

Comment: Is that your URL loaded in your webview???..If yes then its not any problem in that the problem is an internet connection.

Comment: but when load url in mobile browser not slow

connection speed is very well

Comment: Enable Javascript for webview and set WebChromeClient.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private String url = "http://google.com";

    yourWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    yourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

try this